# undelivered mail several days later

Tags: postfix-mta

this is my first time in this group, I have just joined to it.

Please, be patient if I make any mistake, I am learning English right now.

My problem is I have an email server for internal use only. It is Postfix. When someone tries to send an external email, this person get an error email saying undelivered mail returned to sender.

This is correct, the problem is the user get this error several days later, instead of immediately.

I am lost among all the parametes of postfix main.cf file, and I would like to known which parameter I have to change in order to get the error immediately.

Thanks in advance, and kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

Sorry to bother you.

I was looking for the wrong concept. As soon as I looked for how to delete the queue of Postfix, indirectly I found the answer.

You have to change this parameter maximal_queue_lifetime. By default it has 5d, what is 5 days. You can choose between d for days, w for weeks, m for minutes...

Kind regards.